# Continues development for Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have Azure Function running Power Shell that built in a cloud itself (no local files).
I need to copy it to another Azure subscription,
I see a lot of example how to deploy, but my question is how to take all the files of function from Azure and put it in Azure Devops repository with some script, without downloading it to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a direct way to take all the files of function from Azure and put it in Azure DevOps repository without downloading them first.

Basically, we need to download app content to your local machine first, and then push it to Azure DevOps repository.

You can reference the following blogs to do that:

- [Copying an Azure Function App using the Portal, GitHub and Cloud
  Shell](https://thedatafarm.com/tools/first-exploration-of-azure-cli-in-azure-portal-cloudshell/)
- [How to… copy Function Apps](https://lepczynski.it/en/azure_en/azure-copy-function-apps/)